# Seam/Hibernate and PostgreSQL -- Any issues?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, orm, jpa, seam

I'm currently working on a project that makes use of Seam/Hibernate (JPA) on MySQL.  I'm reconsidering moving towards PostgreSQL after investigating some of the features that it provides.  My question is, is there anything I need to worry about with this configuration?  Limitations?  Gotchas?  Things to watch out for?  There will be some BLOBs stored in the database (images, X.509 certificates, etc.)  Will that be a problem using PostgreSQL?  Are there any particular configuration changes or tweaks that I should make in my Hibernate configuration?  Thanks for any advice you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are no particular issues with JPA/Hibernate and PostgreSQL. Actually, I would even say that this combo works very well, especially when dealing with Blobs. PostgreSQL JDBC driver provides a very good implemenation of `java.sql.Blob` (one of the view that supports lazy loading of blobs as mentioned in [this thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2394911#p2394911)). That's the only thing I had to say.